# Crystal Reports - Return list of products with common set of ingredients

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

In Crystal Reports 11, I need to create a report that returns all products in a table that have a set of ingredients listed in a user parameter in common.  In addition, the user needs to be able to enter a varying number of ingredients from one request to the next.  For example:

We have Product_1 which is made up of ingredient_1, ingredient_2, and Ingredient_3.
We have Product_2 which is made up of ingredient_1, ingredient_5, ingredient_6.
we have Product_3 which is made up of ingredient_1, ingredient_2 and inredient_7.

The end user needs to be able to put in up to 3 ingredients and see all formulas that share those ingredients in common.

In query 1, he would put in Ingredient_1 and all three products should be returned with their complete ingredient lists, not just ingredient_1.

In query 2 he would put in ingredient_1 and ingredient_2 which should return products 1 & 2, again with their complete ingredient list.

I need to know how to return all ingredients in a product if it uses all the ingredients entered by the user, without excluding the other ingredients in that product.  I also need to ensure that every product in the database using those specific ingredients are returned.

Comment: What does the data model look like, specifically? Are the users entering strings to be matched to a joined ingredient table?

Comment: What Framework and language are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a query/stored proc issue than one in Crystal Reports.

Your select statement can be like this:

```
DECLARE @ingredient1 VARCHAR(50),
  @ingredient2 VARCHAR(50),
  @ingredient3 VARCHAR(50)


SELECT *
FROM products 
WHERE fld_ProductID IN (SELECT DISTINCT p.fld_ProductID
                        FROM products p
                        WHERE p.fld_formulaID IN (SELECT DISTINCT fld_formulaID 
                                                    FROM formulas 
                                                    WHERE fld_ingredient = @ingredient1
                                                        OR fld_ingredient = @ingredient2
                                                        OR fld_ingredient = @ingredient3)
                        )
```

This will select all formula ids that have one of those ingredients.  It will then get a list of all products that have one of those formulaIDs, and finally it will select all products.  This way if the same product has multiple formulaIDs it will select them all.

Hope this helps.